# SCP Ant task errors with Cause: Could not load a dependent class com/jcraft/jsch/Logger

Tags: eclipse, ant, scp

I am trying to use an SCP task within Ant within Eclipse.

I have downloaded this file: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsch/files/jsch.jar/0.1.50/jsch-0.1.50.jar/download

and put it in `C:\software\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib`
(ant-jsch.jar already exists in this folder) The other folder listed (the one in my home directory) does not exist.

Unfortunately I am getting the following output when trying to use the SCP task:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\rhughes\workspace\project\build-all.xml
scp-test:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\rhughes\workspace\project\build-all.xml:5: Problem: failed to create task or type scp
Cause: Could not load a dependent class com/jcraft/jsch/Logger
   It is not enough to have Ant's optional JARs
   you need the JAR files that the optional tasks depend upon.
   Ant's optional task dependencies are listed in the manual.
Action: Determine what extra JAR files are needed, and place them in one of:
    -C:\software\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib
    -C:\Users\rhughes\.ant\lib
    -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load a dependent class com/jcraft/jsch/Logger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738118/could-not-load-a-dependent-class-com-jcraft-jsch-logger)

Comment: Yes is duplicate, I didn't find that answer before and it has fixed my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @StephaneGrenier yes, see the link from Mark O'Connor above

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue, Its due jsch.jar missing for scp connection in default ant installation and you need to download updated jsch.jar and put into apache-ant/lib directory. Please refer to the below similar post- 
[Ant scp task not working, even with jsch on ant/lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374105/ant-scp-task-not-working-even-with-jsch-on-ant-lib)

Thanks
Ajay Sony